# Guidance on MIPS Merge Program

Tags: arrays, merge, mips

I am trying to write a program that will merge two ordered lists(arrays) into a new ordered list. So far I've tried loading individual elements of each array into separate registers and then comparing them to one another on a case by case basis ( both arrays are separate at this point) and then, following the comparison, creating the new array with an ordered list of all arrays from the first two.

I was wondering though, would it be simpler to merge both arrays initially (regardless of ordered or not) and then order the elements of said array?

Comment: It is simpler to write code that concatenates two arrays and then re-sorts them; however, that is not efficient and doesn't take advantage of the knowledge that the two inputs are already sorted.  So, your first idea of merging them elementwise into a new ordered lists is likely the right way to do it.

Comment: Since you already have two ordered lists, your merge operation is _exactly_ what the merge part of `mergesort` does. So, look at the merge _function_ in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort